# Single-letter words at the end of line

Tags: grammar

I am a beginner and I write article in slovak language. There is a rule to not leave single-letter words or preposition at the end of line (for example a, i, na, pre etc.) but to move them to the next one.

I know that I can use "~", but in this article there are a lot of single letters and prepositions, so I cannot use it every time. Can somebody help me, please? :(

Thank´s.

Comment: this has come up before, but in classic tex (latex or pdflatex or xelatex) there really is no other solution than using `~`  it's only one keystroke, so really no harder than a space, or at least you may be able to persuade yourself that that is the case.

Comment: note if you leave it until the document is almost done it should be easy to change `.. na ` to `.. na~`  using your text editor.

Comment: Thank you very much. :)
I wrote article, so I have to change it. :( 
But I have a problem. I have 
a\textsubscript{1}v\textsubscript{1}+ ... + a\textsubscript{i}v\textsubscript{i} $\in$ C~pre a\textsubscript{i} ... but it does not work. What can I do?

Comment: is that related to your question about words at end of line???  I can not guess why you have `\textsubscript` isn't that a mathematical expression? why have you only got `\in` in mathematics and the rest of the math expression set as text????

Comment: Because I forgot to change it. :) When I wrote it, I did not know that I should write it in mathematics (I am beginner).
Yes. I do not want to have "pre" at the end. But "~" does not work. Can you help me?

Comment: You have `~pre` that stops the line break _before_ pre, but you want to stop a line break _after_ pre so it should be `pre~....`

Comment: I didn't notice it. Thank you.